# Extra intervals before and after flushright environment

Tags: spacing, environments

I am preparing questionnaire template in LaTeX.

**I have** the following code (simplified):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\framebox{\parbox{4cm}{
    \textbf{3. How often do you have a headache?}\\
    \textit{(Choose one option)}\begin{flushright}
        never 0

        seldom 1

        often 2
    \end{flushright}            
}}
\end{document}
```

**Output** looks like this:

[image]

**My questions are:**

- Why I get the blank lines(marked by red color on picture for convenience) before and after the flushright environment ?
- How to remove them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\flushright` and `\flushleft` are defined using `\trivlist`:

```
\def\flushright{\trivlist \raggedleft\item\relax}
\def\endflushleft{\endtrivlist}
```

and this adds some additional vertical space. If you don't want this additional space. you could use the `\raggedleft`, `\raggedright` commands instead of the `\flushright`, `\flushleft` environments. Another option would be to set `\topset` (and `\parskip`, and `\partopset`, if necessary) to `0pt`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\framebox{\parbox{4cm}{
    \textbf{3. How often do you have a headache?}\\
    \textit{(Choose one option)}\begin{flushright}
        never 0

        seldom 1

        often 2
    \end{flushright}            
}}

\framebox{\parbox{4cm}{\setlength\topsep{0pt}
    \textbf{3. How often do you have a headache?}\\
    \textit{(Choose one option)}\begin{flushright}
        never 0

        seldom 1

        often 2
    \end{flushright}            
}}


\framebox{\parbox{4cm}{
    \textbf{3. How often do you have a headache?}\\
    \textit{(Choose one option)}

\begingroup\raggedleft
        never 0

        seldom 1

        often 2\par
    \endgroup
}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is that `topset` or `topsep`?