# Own headings for an article

Tags: sectioning

I've got a litte problem in making my own headings, my goal is something like this:
[image: Number, Heading, Text]

my current code looks like this

```
%-- Preamble ------------------------------------
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

%-- Nur für Debugging
%    \usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%-- Import packages -----------------------------
% Anpassung an deutsche Sprache
% Umlaute ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Umlaute/Sonderzeichen wie äüöß direkt im Quelltext verwenden (CodePage).
%   Erlaubt automatische Trennung von Worten mit Umlauten.
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


% Seitenränder und Zeilenabstände
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}

% Schriften und Farben
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl} % Für farbige Tabellen
\usepackage[default,osfigures,scale=1]{opensans}

% Textumgebungen
\usepackage{multicol} % Text in mehreren Kolumnen darstellen

% Hyperrefs und PDF Information
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Tabellen
\usepackage{booktabs}

% Inhaltsverzeichnis umbenennen
\usepackage{tocbibind}

% Listen
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist} % Einfache Liste Umgebung
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures

% Kopf und Fusszeilen
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Grafiken und Textbausteine
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos} % Absolue Positionierung
%    \usepackage[dvips,final]{graphicx} % Einbinden von JPG-Grafiken ermöglichen für
%dvi format
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics} % keepaspectratio
\usepackage{floatflt} % zum Umfließen von Bildern
\graphicspath{{pictures/}} % hier liegen die Bilder des Dokuments

% Mathe
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

% Acronym Support
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

%-- Seitenstil ---------------------------
% Setzen der Seitenränder
\geometry{top=25mm,left=30mm,right=30mm,bottom=30mm,a4paper}
\setlength{    \marginparwidth}{20mm}

% Kein Einzug
\setlength{    \parindent}{0cm} 

% Konfiguration für das textpos
\setlength{    \TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{    \TPVertModule}{    \TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{0mm}{0mm}

% Kopf und Fusszeilen
\setlength{    \headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

%-- Aufgabe mit Trennlinie --------------------------------
\newcounter{cntaufgabe}
\newcounter{cntfrage}
\setcounter{cntfrage}{1}
\newcommand{    \resetaufgabe}{%
\par
\vspace{10mm}
\leftskip=0cm
\setcounter{cntfrage}{1}
}
\newcommand{    \aufgabe}[1]{%
\stepcounter{cntaufgabe}
\resetaufgabe
\vspace{2ex}
\begin{flushright}
\leftskip=-2cm
\textbf{    \thecntaufgabe}
\end{flushright}
\hspace{5mm}
\textbf{#1}
\vspace{1mm}
\hrule
\vspace{2ex}%
}
%-- Frage mit Trennlinie --------------------------------
\newcommand{    \frage}[1]{%
\par
\vspace{5mm}
\leftskip=1.4cm
\alph{cntfrage})
\hspace{1mm}
\textit{#1}
\vspace{5mm}
\par
\leftskip=2cm
\stepcounter{cntfrage}
}


\begin{document}
%-- Deckblatt -----------------------------------
%    \input{allgemein/deckblatt.tex}
%-- Inhaltsverzeichnis --------------------------
\tableofcontents
\newpage 

\section{Title}

\subsection{Subtitle}

\aufgabe{Dies ist eine Aufgabe}
\blindtext
\setcounter{cntaufgabe}{16}
\setcounter{cntfrage}{16}
\aufgabe{Dies ist noch eine Aufgabe}
\frage{Was bedeutet ICMP?}
Internet Control Messages Protocol
\setcounter{cntfrage}{16}
\frage{Was bedeutet CSMA/CD?}
\blindtext
\aufgabe{Dies ist noch eine Aufgabe 23}
\setcounter{cntaufgabe}{111121545}
\aufgabe{Dies ist noch eine Aufgabe 34}
\begin{align}
e=mc^2
\end{align}
\resetaufgabe % muss mach aufgaben aufgerufen werden
\blindtext
\par
\blindtext
\begin{description}
  \item[First]    \hfill     \\
\The first item 
  \item[Second]    \hfill     \\
\ The second item
  \item[Third]    \hfill     \\
\ The third etc     \ldots
\end{description}

Plain text. 
\underline{    \hfill     \\
\}

\subsection{Another subtitle}

More plain text.
\blinddocument

%-- Appendix --------------------------
\appendix

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\end{document}
```

but unfortunately it looks so

[image]

can anyone please advise me how i can achieve it? 
Thx in advance Liz

**Solved**
The solution that Thruston mentioned in the comments worked for me!

Comment: Welcome to the site. You may visit http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436 to get yourself familiarized further with our format.

Comment: Kindly consider posting a complete MWE starting from `\documentclass{..}` and ending at `\end{document}` so as to save us from some typing and guessing work (regarding the packages loaded)

Comment: What do the boxes represent and which of the elements should be where?

Comment: Your problem is that `flushright` creates a list with vertical space before and after.  See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27696/extra-intervals-before-and-after-flushright-environment).  Try replacing the whole `flushright` part with `\leavevmode\llap{\bf\thecntaufgabe\kern2cm}`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much, it works like a charm.

Comment: @werner first left box the number, the box next to the number is the title and the bigone is just the some text

Comment: By the way how can i flag the question as answered?

Comment: @Thruston would have to write a proper answer, then you can accept that. (And by the way, [use `\bfseries`, not `\bf`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516).)

Comment: @Thruston `\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[2cm][l]{...}}` would use only documented LaTeX commands.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I've added a proper answer now.  T.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `\flushright` environment with something that does not create vertical space.

In plain/primitive TeX:

```
\leavevmode\llap{\bf\thecntaufgabe\kern2cm}
```

Or if you prefer to work at the LaTeX level:

```
\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[2cm][l]{\textbf{\thecntaufgabe}}}
```

as suggested in the comments.

Note that these two solutions are not *quite* the same: the original "plain" version sets 2cm of space after the number; the LaTeX version sets the number in a 2cm box.  If you wanted the latter behaviour in plain Tex, you could try:

```
\leavevmode\llap{\hbox to 2cm{\bf\thecntaufgabe\hss}}
```

Also note that while one *can* freely mix TeX primitives, plain TeX macros, and LaTeX commands in any TeX document, there is an open question about whether this is a good idea.  The general consensus on this forum seems to be that One Should Stick to LaTeX At All Times.

Personally I prefer sticking close to plain TeX so that I know more clearly what's going on, since LaTeX commands often have hidden surprises (as the OP discovered with `flushright`).  But this does mean that I spent a lot of time reading the TeXbook.
Your mileage may vary (as they say).

Comment: Don't use `\bf` but `\bfseries`

Comment: @egreg fair point, but `\bf` is shorter to type, and since normal LaTeX defines `\bf` as `\normalshape\bfseries` it was appropriate to the original question, since she's unlikely to want any bold italics in the section number box...

Comment: `\bf` was declared obsolete around twenty years ago. The LaTeX kernel *doesn't* define it. Some classes do (in particular the standard ones, but just for backward compatibility).

Comment: Yeah sure I've read [l2tabu](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/) as well, but I still think most of Knuth's original design is generally simpler and easier to type.  And if you read my solution closely, you might notice that I was *trying* to show a Plain Tex solution in the first part.  I put `\textbf` in the suggested LaTex solution.

Comment: The answer is about LaTeX, not Plain TeX. I'm not against using low level constructions, when the corresponding LaTeX code would be unnecessarily heavy; but the font selection commands should be the LaTeX ones. Trying your answer with `memoir` would give a puzzling error. Don't confuse primitives with Plain TeX macros.

Comment: Well if you like I can put the LaTex solution at the top and push the plain solution further down.  I only included both because they had both been discussed in the comments and I thought it might be informative for readers to see both.