# How can I decrease the vertical space under an environment in a custom command?

Tags: spacing

I'd like to manipulate the vertical space under a custom command I defined. How can I do that?

(all these years and I actually have never looked into this before...)

### Picture

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
setspace,
lipsum
}

\newcommand{\something}[1]{\begin{flushleft}\large\sffamily{#1}\end{flushleft}}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\lipsum[1]
\something{Words}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

### Solution

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\something}[1]{%
    \par\addvspace{\topsep}%
    \noindent\begingroup\raggedright\sffamily#1\par\nobreak\addvspace{0.15\baselineskip}\endgroup
    \@afterheading\@afterindentfalse
}
```

Comment: This depends on the settings of the `flushleft` environment. I am unsure, which skipping it's introduced by it. Perhaps something like `\topskip` etc.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27696/extra-intervals-before-and-after-flushright-environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to use `flushright`, but simply `\raggedright`; also you're missing a `\nopagebreak`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\something}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}%
  \noindent\begingroup\raggedright\sffamily#1\par\endgroup
  \nopagebreak
  \noindent\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\something{Words}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Don't leave any blank line between `\something{...}` and the text that follows.

[image]

I removed `\onehalfspacing` because it's against my religion. `;-)` Add it, if you really have to spoil your document. `;-)`

A perhaps better solution that also allows blank lines after `\something{...}` employs the internals used after section headings.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\something}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}%
  \noindent\begingroup\raggedright\sffamily#1\par\nobreak\endgroup
  \@afterheading\@afterindentfalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\something{Words}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to be quite sound as well, but in general I do not intend to fully delete the vertical space, just manipulate it as I said in the op. Thank you for the second solution, I like this one more than the first one because I also want to leave blank line in the code. :)

Comment: Ah figured it out myself, I edited it into `\sffamily#1\par\addvspace{0.15\baselineskip}\nobreak\endgroup`. Or some other factor might prove to look ok as well. :)

Comment: @henry `\nobreak` should go before the spacing.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Will update the op with what I was looking for.

Comment: I wanted to test and enable the indentation after the command again. Deleting `\@afterheading\@afterindentfalse` lead to a satisfactory result. Is the definition still ok then? (deleting onle `\@afterindentfalse` didn't produce the indentation somehow)

Comment: @henry Just `\@afterindentfalse` should be removed: `\@afterheading` sets up the “no page break” mechanism.

Comment: Hm, ok. Weird, it works in the MWE but not in my main document. :/

Answer (score 3):

`flushleft` is defined as `trivlist`, as such it uses the `topsep`, `\partopsep` and `\parskip` lengths (added!) for the top and the bottom spacing to the next text content. In order to reduce the spacing below, it's best to set this elastic lengths to `0pt` within a `\begingroup...\endgroup` pair, but issue `\vspace{\topsep}` before, in order to maintain some distance to the text above.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{setspace,
lipsum%
}


\newcommand{\something}[1]{\begingroup
  \vspace{\topsep}% Use the old top distance
  \setlength\partopsep{0pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}\setlength\parskip{0pt}% Set the top seps to zero
  \begin{flushleft}\large\sffamily{#1}%
  \end{flushleft}\endgroup%
}%


\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\lipsum[1]
\something{Words}
\lipsum[2]
\something{Other Words}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, perfect.

Comment: @henry: egreg's solution is better, in my point of view ;-)

Comment: He does not provide a way to touch the vertical space below the command which is what I was looking for.

Comment: I re-set the solution mark to egreg's post as it seems to be indeed better. I hope it is ok for you.

Comment: @henry: I am heavily disappointed :-P

Comment: :) Also these are some words just so I get above the minimum character limit.

Comment: @henry: You are a cunning fox ;-) -- Well, no, egreg's solution is better -- I learned again some stuff, as usual!